# How to define a a custom method with angular $resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory 'Product', ($resource) ->

  Product = $resource '/api/v1/products/:id', {},
    all:    { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
    edit:   { method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/products/:id/edit' }

  Product.prototype.images = ->
    this.$promise.then (data) ->
      image = $resource "/api/v1/products/#{data.id}/images"
      image.query().$promise.then (data) -> data

  return Product
```

The `images` method defined on prototype works, but I'm wondering if this is possible to do using the custom method DSL that I used to defined `all` and `edit`?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define a method to get the images of a particular product, one way to do it is changing the resource configuration to default to the id of the resource "instance" and adding a controller variable to the resource route.

```
$resource '/api/v1/products/:id/:controller', { id: '@id' },
  all:
    method: 'GET'
    isArray: true
  edit:
    method: 'GET'
    params: controller: 'edit'
  getImages:
    method: 'GET'
    isArray: true
    params: controller: 'images'
```

Now you can call the method from the resource directly: `Product.getImages({id: 'aProductId'})` or from the instance: `product.$getImages()`

Comment: That's not really the same thing. My implementation allows me to call an instance method. For example, product = Product.all(id: 1); images = product.images(). Can this be done?

Comment: Yes it can be done, I edited the the answer accordingly. hope that helped

Comment: It doesn't work. I get `api/v1/products/images 404 ` -- the product id is not passed in viw '@id' from the instance.